# How to implement Schema.org markup in Ajax web applications?

Tags: seo, schema.org, ajax

I developed a web application using Ajax. Now I want to implement Schema.org markup in the application.

I know how I can implement it, but I am confused how search engines crawl Ajax pages of the application.

Comment: Your question title asks how to implement it, but your question body says that you know how.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is a transport mechanism.

You implement the markup the same way you do any other markup on a page. These are only attributes of an element. No different. You add them the same way you do any other element with attributes on a page.